# Markup of function argument name in jsdoc?

Tags: jsdoc

How to mark or make reference function argument in jsdoc/jsdoc3.

For example:

```
/** 
 * Build xxx.
 * cfg is optional.
 *
 * @param {Object} cfg  config
 * @function
 */
function build(engine, cfg) { ... }
```

What markup used to wrap `cfg` in `cfg is optional.` description?

Answer (score 0):

I see [one possible way](http://speakingjs.com/es5/ch29.html) by enclosing into `tt` HTML tag:

```
/**
 * Repeat <tt>str</tt> several times.
 * @param {string} str The string to repeat.
 * @param {number} [times=1] How many times to repeat the string.
 * @returns {string}
 */
repeat: function(str, times) { ... }
```